# Parenthesized binary tree, while != null won't work

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

I'm working on a program that accepts a string which represents a prefix format binary expression (such as (A(B(C)(D))(E(F)(G))) ). I've been stuck on a part of the algorithm to add the data to nodes based on the parenthesis from separate stacks (after A for root, '('indicates a left node while ')' followed by '(' indicates a right. My code seems to run well enough until I hit the following code:

```
if (focus != null && val == '(') {
                    char nodeVal = tree.pop();
                    Node node = new Node(nodeVal);
                    focus = root;
                    while(focus != null) {
                        focus = focus.leftNode;
                    }
                    focus = node;
```

It passes through the "if (focus != null)", but when it hits the while loop, it either returns an error, doesn't add the new node or creates an infinite loop (based on a few variations I've been trying. The full code for the method is as follows if it helps:

```
public void constructTree(String input) {
            
            for(int i = input.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                if(input.charAt(i) == '(' || input.charAt(i) == ')') {
                    paren.push(input.charAt(i));
                }
                else {
                    tree.push(input.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            while(!paren.isEmpty()) {
                char val = paren.pop();
                Node focus = root;
                Node parent;
                
    
                if (val == ')' && root == null) {
                    throw new InvalidTreeSyntax("Your tree cannot be empty");
                }
                if (root == null) {
                    char nodeVal = tree.pop();
                    Node node = new Node(nodeVal);
                    
                    root = node;
                }
                                
                if (focus != null && val == '(') {
                        char nodeVal = tree.pop();
                        Node node = new Node(nodeVal);
                        focus = root;
                        while(focus != null) {
                            focus = focus.leftNode;
                        }
                        focus = node;
                        
                        
                    }
                else if (focus != null  && val == ')' && paren.peek()== '(' || paren.peek() == null) {
                    char nodeVal = tree.pop();
                    Node node = new Node(nodeVal);
                    paren.pop();
                    while(focus!= null) {
                        focus = focus.rightNode;
                    }
                    focus = node;
                    
                }

            }
        }
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake, but after a belly full of turkey and not enough sleep, I'm brain dead and need some help!

Comment: I see a couple of assignments to local variable 'focus' (of the form 'focus = node') and then you do nothing with it, at which point the variable vanishes at the end of the outer while-loop.  The net effect is that all the code that determines a value for 'focus' does nothing at all.

Comment: That much makes sense, however I can't get out of the inner while loop to even reach that occurrence of focus = node. If i put the focus = node into the inner while loop, I get an infinite loop where nothing ever gets added to the root node

Comment: Then you've got a Node where its left pointer is buggered up.  Given you do nothing visible with the 'new Node' that you create, it's difficult to know what.  What's the leftNode of the root point to?  Are you sure the end of the chain is set to null?  Nothing you have posted can answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive solution.

```
record Node(char value, Node left, Node right) {}

static Node constructTree(Deque<Integer> que) {
    if (que.peek() != '(')
        return null;
    que.pop();
    if (que.peek() == '(' || que.peek() == ')')
        throw new RuntimeException("node value expected");
    char nodeValue = (char)(int)que.pop();
    Node left = constructTree(que);
    Node right = constructTree(que);
    if (que.peek() != ')')
        throw new RuntimeException("')' expected");
    que.pop();
    return new Node(nodeValue, left, right);
}

static Node consturctTree(String s) {
    return constructTree(s.chars().boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String source = "(A(B(C)(D))(E(F)(G)))";
    Node root2 = consturctTree(source);
    System.out.println(root2);
}
```

output: (edited)

```
Node[value=A,
    left=Node[value=B,
        left=Node[value=C, left=null, right=null],
        right=Node[value=D, left=null, right=null]],
    right=Node[value=E,
        left=Node[value=F, left=null, right=null],
        right=Node[value=G, left=null, right=null]]]
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The only thing I needed to change was that I'm implementing this to accept user input, so I had to add a while(!stack.isEmpty) and i worked fine from there